# Closing opened file descriptors in child process

Tags: unix, fork, parent-child, file-descriptor, setrlimit

Is there a way to iterate through already open file descriptors (opened by parent process) and close them one by one in child process?

OS: Unix.

Reason for closure: RLIMIT_NOFILE limit of the setrlimit() constrains the number of file descriptors that a process may allocate.If we want to restrict our child process by setting this limit, it depends on the already allocated file descriptors.

Trying to set this limit in a child process is restricted as the parent process has some open file descriptors and hence we cannot set this limit lesser than that number.

Example: If parent process has 10 file descriptors allocated and we wish to limit the child process file descriptor number to less than 10 (Say 3), we would need to close 7 file descriptors inside the child process.

The solution to this can benefit all those who want to restrict their child process from creating new files or opening new network connections.

Comment: *"If parent process has 10 file descriptors allocated..."*: what does "allocated" mean for you? Because file descriptors are either opened or closed. The word allocation is associated with memory management...

Comment: Correction: I meant to say 10 Opened file descriptors of parent process, thanks for correction thkala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following idiom is not uncommon (this is taken from the C part of [MIMEDefang](http://www.mimedefang.org/)):

```
/* Number of file descriptors to close when forking */
#define CLOSEFDS 256
...

static void
closefiles(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<CLOSEFDS; i++) {
        (void) close(i);
   }
}
```

(That's from mimedefang-2.78, the implementation has been [changed slightly in later releases](https://github.com/The-McGrail-Foundation/MIMEDefang/blob/v2.86/mimedefang.c#L2681).)

It is something of a hack (as the MIMEDefang code freely admitted). In many cases it's more useful to start at FD 3 (or `STDERR_FILENO+1`) instead of 0. `close()` returns `EBADF` with an invalid FD, but this doesn't usually present problems (at least not in C, in other languages an exception may be thrown).

Since you can determine the file-descriptor upper limit with `getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE,...)` which is [defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getrlimit.html) as:

> RLIMIT_NOFILE
>
> This is a number one greater than the maximum value that the system may assign to a newly-created descriptor. If this limit is exceeded, functions that allocate a file descriptor shall fail with errno set to [EMFILE]. This limit constrains the number of file descriptors that a process may allocate.

you can use this (subtracting 1) as the upper limit of the loop.
The above and `ulimit -n`, `getconf OPEN_MAX` and `sysconf(OPEN_MAX)` should all agree.

Since `open()` always assigns the lowest free FD, the maximum number of open files and the highest FD+1 are the same number.

To detemine what fds are open, instead of `close()` use a no-op `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR)` which will return `EBADF` if the fd is not open (there's no obvious benefit to calling `lseek()` for a conditional `close()` though). `socat`'s `filan` loops over 0 .. `FD_SETSIZE` calling `fstat()`/`fstat64()`.

The [libslack `daemon` utility](http://libslack.org/daemon/) which daemonizes arbitrary processes also uses this brute-force approach (while making sure to keep the first three descriptors open when used under `inetd`).

In the case where your program can track file handles it is preferable to do so, or use `FD_CLOEXEC` where available. However, should you wish to code defensively, you might prefer to distrust your parent process, say for an external handler/viewer process started by a browser, e.g. like this [long-lived and ancient Mozilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=147659) on Unix platforms.

For the paranoid (do you want your PDF viewer to inherit every open Firefox FD including your cache, and open TCP connections?):

```
#!/bin/bash
# you might want to use the value of "ulimit -n" instead of picking 255
for ((fd=3; fd<=255; fd++)); do
  exec {fd}<&- # close
done
exec /usr/local/bin/xpdf "$@"
```

**Update** after 15 years this issue was resolved in Firefox 58 (2018) when process creation was changed from  the Netscape Portable Runtime (NSPR) API to use LaunchApp.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no general way to iterate over open file descriptors in Unix/POSIX. The traditional way to handle the problem that you are describing is to keep track of them in your own code, if needed using a data structure such as an array or list, and close them in the child process after `fork()` but before `exec()`.

Some operating systems, however, offer a potential solution if you are calling `exec()` after creating the child process. Either by [setting the `FD_CLOEXEC` flag for a file descriptor using `fcntl()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6125068/507519) or with the `O_CLOEXEC` flag for `open()` the operating system is instructed to close that specific file descriptor before calling `exec()`. You will have to consult the documentation of your target operating system(s) to find out if and which of those flags are supported.

Comment: Can i loop through file descriptor numbers from 0 to MAX ALLOWED file descriptors and take a call based on the output of dup(int fildes) function ? Since dup() if failed, returns '-1'.

Is that a bad way or it is another crude way of knowing the information i am looking for?

Comment: @user2136293: there are a *lot* of assumptions in your proposal that can and will break your code: 1. You are assuming that you can reliably find out what the maximum FD number is. Apart from MAX_INT there is no other reliable limit. 2. You are assuming that that number will be "reasonable". Are you going to probe 2^31 FDs? 3. you are assuming that you can blindly `close()` any file descriptor that you don't like. What if one of your libraries keeps an open FD for some specific reason?

Comment: @user2136293: What is it that you are trying to do anyway? [What is your real problem?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)