# How to restart or start a process with closing all file descriptors in C

Tags: c, restart

I want to restart my process cleanly. So I tried to call `execv()`.

It seemed to work well. However, it keeps sockets and files opened.
Is there a way to restart (this) process and close all file/sockets?

I don't want to make a zombie process, I don't use `fork()`.

Comment: Set the `close-on-exec` flag on all the descriptors that you want to be closed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125068/what-does-the-fd-cloexec-fcntl-flag-do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like any other file descriptors, sockets are not closed across `exec` or `fork`.  If you want them closed, you will need to close them yourself.  There are three possible approches.

The cleanest solution is to keep track of all your sockets and close them before calling `exec`.  Depending on your application, this might or might not be possible.

Another solution is to set the "close on exec" flag on your sockets just after creating them, using a pair of `fcntl` calls (`F_GETFD`, add `FD_CLOEXEC`, then `F_SETFD`).  Do not forget the sockets you obtained from `accept`.

If that cannot be done, you can brutally close all of your file descriptors just before calling `exec` using something like the following:

```
n = sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX);
for(i = 3; i < n; i++)
    close(i);
```

Comment: Not 'brutal', but rather *definitive*  and clear.   You can either "close on exec" every fd >2, OR you can close() every fd > 2.  Otherwise you are permitting a backdoor.