# Pipe issue: first child writes too much in to pipe

Tags: c, linux, fork, system-calls, execvp

I'm trying to write a program in `C` that creates 2 child processes with each one of them executing an `execvp`.

My problem is that the first child writes too much input into the pipe from which the other child reads.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

//unnamed pipe
int pipeFd[2], statusFirst,statusSecond;
pid_t childPidOne,childPidTwo;

if(pipe(pipeFd) < 0){
    perror("Pipe error:\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

switch(childPidOne = fork()){
    case -1:
        perror("First Fork error:\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    case 0:
        printf("First child\n");
        close(pipeFd[1]);
        if( (execvp(argv[1], &argv[1])) < 0){
            perror("First execvp error:\n");
        }
        printf("End First cild\n");
        exit(0);
    default:
        //Do nothing
        break;  
}

switch(childPidTwo = fork()){
    case -1:
        perror("Second Fork error:\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    case 0:
        printf("Second cild\n");
        close(pipeFd[0]);
        if( (execvp(argv[3], &argv[3])) < 0){
            perror("Second execvp error:\n");
        }
        printf("End Second cild\n");
        exit(0);
    default:
        //Do nothing
        break;  
}


close(pipeFd[0]);
close(pipeFd[1]);   


if( (waitpid(childPidOne,&statusFirst,WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED)) < 0 ){
    perror("First waitpid error:\n");
}else{
    if (WIFEXITED(statusFirst)) {
       printf("First exited, status=%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(statusFirst));
    } else if (WIFSIGNALED(statusFirst)) {
       printf("First killed by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(statusFirst));
    } else if (WIFSTOPPED(statusFirst)) {
       printf("First stopped by signal %d\n", WSTOPSIG(statusFirst));
    } else if (WIFCONTINUED(statusFirst)) {
       printf("First continued\n");
    }
}


if( (waitpid(childPidTwo,&statusSecond,WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED)) < 0 ){
    perror("Second waitpid error:\n");
}
if (WIFEXITED(statusSecond)) {
   printf("Second exited, status=%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(statusSecond));
  } else if (WIFSIGNALED(statusSecond)) {
   printf("Second killed by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(statusSecond));
  } else if (WIFSTOPPED(statusSecond)) {
   printf("Second stopped by signal %d\n", WSTOPSIG(statusSecond));
  } else if (WIFCONTINUED(statusSecond)) {
      printf("Second continued\n");
      }

   exit(0);
return 0;
  }
```

Maybe I have a wrong understanding of how pipe + fork + execvp work so let me tell you what I'm doing in my code:

1. I create an unnamed pipe - both childs use the same pipe
2. I'll create two childs by forking them
3. Since I execute my program like this: `./pipeline [FIRST SYSTEM CALL] | [SECOND SYSTEM CALL]` or just to give you an example:`./pipeline echo Hello | wc -m` I close the reading site of the pipe
4. And then call `execvp(argv[1], &argv[1])`

And this is where the error happens (I guess):
I am never closing the writing side until the second child does because `execvp` will never return if it succeeds.

And I know that `execvp` will not close open file descriptors ( it can be closed by using a flag in `fcntl` as mentioned in [What does the FD_CLOEXEC flag do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125068/what-does-the-fd-cloexec-fcntl-flag-do) ).

## Example

Let me give you an example.

```
echo Hello | wc -m
```

outputs the result

> 6

Because the system call `wc` (word count) counts the characters (`-m`) in a given `String`

That is correct because hello = 5 + 1 (which is `\n` or `\0` I guess) and that makes 6.

Now, running my program gives the result

> 56

Or to get more information

```
echo hello | wc
```

outputs

> 1 (line) 1 (word)  6 (characters)

And `./pipeline echo hello | wc`

outputs

> 3 (lines) 9 (word) 56 (characters)

I've searched for days but I can't figure it out.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're using `./pipeline echo hello | wc` to run your program, then it's not doing what you think it is.  Your program is seeing `argv[1] == echo`, `[2] == hello` and _nothing else_. The (combined) output of your program is then piped into `wc`. To (fully) achieve what I think you want to do, you need to escape the pipe character and detect it in your code (so you know which parts of the command-line to pass into each child process).

Comment: @TripeHound , I escaped the character manually by typing ./pipeline echo hello \| wc and it kind of worked for me, except the fact the second child starts wc in the interactive mode (waits for input and ctrl+d to mark end of input). This gives me the correct result of 1 1 6. This means that the input of the first child is ignored. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself.

Forgot to use `dup2`.

Just type the `dup2` command after the `close` command and you will be fine.