# Why close_fds=False sometimes hangs the process in Python 2?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I noticed that in Python3 subprocesses the default for Popen parameter `close_fds` was changed from `False` to `True` and I wondered what was the **reason** and whether it is a good practice to **almost always** set `close_fds` to `True` (as I'm still using Python 2.7).

I have found a link showing an issue with `close_fds=False`.

https://bugs.python.org/issue7213

Unfortunately, it isn't clear to me why it so happens.

```py
import subprocess as sub
p1 = sub.Popen(['cat'], stdin=sub.PIPE, stdout=sub.PIPE, close_fds=False)
p2 = sub.Popen(['grep', 'a'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=sub.PIPE, close_fds=False)
p1.stdin.write("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n")
p1.stdin.close()
p2.stdout.read()  # Hangs on Python 2
```

The program hangs on Python2, does not on Python3 and does not hang at all if `close_fds` is set to `True`. So I wonder... What was the actual issue there?

**EDIT:** It hangs on my Python 2.6 and stopped hanging on 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What was the actual issue there?

With Python 2.6 the file handle of the write end of the `p1.stdin` pipe is inherited by `p2`, which doesn't care or know about it and so leaves it open. Consequently, although the parent process does `p1.stdin.close()`, the write pipe remains open and thus the `cat` doesn't detect EOF on its input and keeps waiting for data from the pipe, blocking the whole process chain.

With Python 2.7 calls of [`fcntl(…, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125068/what-does-the-fd-cloexec-fcntl-flag-do) follow the creation of the `stdin` and `stdout` pipes, so that the write pipe end isn't inherited by `p2` and effectively closed by `p1.stdin.close()`.